# Websocket dropping requests / freezing intermittently

Tags: javascript, java, browser, webserver

- [start.bat](http://pastebin.com/wvQYLJrV)
- Server.jar

  - [server/Server.java](http://pastebin.com/u9DU4F9a)
  - [server/HTTPServer.java](http://pastebin.com/T05VBh1L)
  - [server/WebSocket.java](http://pastebin.com/u9DU4F9a)
  - [server/util/FileUtil.java](http://pastebin.com/UpPW7uvD)
- root

  - [index.html](http://pastebin.com/0RmzwRJp)
  - [script.js](http://pastebin.com/jv2EnDz7)
  - [style.css](http://pastebin.com/93CnYSsf)
  - favicon.ico
- error

  - [error.html](http://pastebin.com/Ns9Rnpi5)
  - [script.js](http://pastebin.com/VjzuWZ0w)
  - [error.js](http://pastebin.com/DSrJK4NJ)
  - [style.css](http://pastebin.com/TfCs0xX2)
  - favicon.ico

There's alot of files that can't possibly cause the problem, but i decided to include them anyway so you can try this if you want to. Also i've added a couple of `System.out.println(arg0);`'s for debugging

**On Google Chrome:** works as intended when refreshing with ctr+r or ctr+shit+r. But if you press the refresh button it loads everything but the WebSocket request freezes for a little while. When done freezing the server picks up a couple (2?) requests but the first lines are `null`, therefor the server stops handling the request and waits for a new request. Then the server picks up a correct WebSocket request and everything continues on as intended. But if you refresh while it is frozen, the server connects to the previous WebSocket and correctly sends `index.html` and `style.css`, but fails to send `script.js` and throws a `java.net.SocketException` and a `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` because it tries to read a negative number (-124?) bytes of data.

**On FireFox:** Same as google chrome, but it happens randomly instead of when the refresh button is pressed.

I also can't connect to the server if a WebSocket is opened, wich is probably because the WebSocket reads the request that the ServerSocket is supposed to read, but i'm not sure about this and i have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I know its too late, but have you found why this was happening and if so how did you handle it?

Comment: I fixed it somehow, but i don't remember how. Why do you want to know? just interested or are you having the same problem?
If it's important i can go searching for differences in my code when i have more time.